# Updated Nested Collection field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of stores which each element would look like below:

```
{
 "Name":"Contosco",
 "OperationalDetails" : [ 
        {
            "OperationalDay" : "Sun-Thu",
            "StartTime" : "10:00 AM",
            "EndTime" : "06:00 PM"
        }, 
        {
            "OperationalDay" : "Fri-Sat",
            "StartTime" : "04:00 PM",
            "EndTime" : "09:30 PM"
        }
    ],
}
```

I need to update the EndTime of all the OperationalDetails of all stores to "06:00 PM"

I'm running the below  query

```
db.stores.update({"Sector.Code": 'GROC'}, { '$set': {"OperationalDetails.$[].EndTime" : '06:00 PM'} },{multi:true} );
```

But I'm getting the following response

```
Cannot apply array updates to non-array element OperationalDetails: { 0: { EndTime: "06:00 PM" } }
```

Any idea how I could achieve this.

Comment: probably there is null or other values in `OperationalDetails` so you should check condition in query part `{ "Sector.Code": 'GROC', OperationalDetails: { $type: "array" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iDJWqHEhUFu) the syntax you have is working fine.

The error means it's trying to apply an array update to a none array value, this means you have a document that matches your query but the `OperationalDetails` is not an array but a different type.

To find this object you can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/), like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  OperationalDetails: {
    $not: {
      $type: 4
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/68r4JJ4KINi)